# Cognos data not updating into new financial year

Tags: date, cognos, financial

thanks for viewing...

Cognos pulls info from a 'Maginus' Oracle database.

We are unable to pull any data from within the new financial year or see any ongoing dates.

Maginus - a (frustrating) tool developed for the business to run sales, stock, staff, working abilities and so on.

I wondered if there was a manunal step anybody knows about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seemingly dragging doing some re-linking in the categories window sorted this out.

I don't think there were any filters but i will keep an eye out for this in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no filter within the framework that filters the data by year. Otherwise the framework just pulls from the database so there should be no problem getting the newest data.